# Filtrar locais em uma area de X km

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, geolocalização

Estou tentando montar um pequeno projeto onde tenho uma lista de locais e consigo filtrar os mesmos de acordo com uma quantidade x de km. Ex: Filtrar todos os lugares em um raio de 5km da minha localização atual.

Tenho um `Json` com alguns locais da minha cidade e quando tento fazer um filtro de 2km o `Json` retorna em branco, porém se passo 50km como parâmetro todos os dados são retornados. Não estou conseguindo identificar onde estou errando.

Segue trecho do código:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Location = mongoose.model('Location');

// create an export function to encapsulate the controller's methods
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res, next) {
    res.json(200, {
      status: 'Location API is running.',
    });
  },
  findLocation: function(req, res, next) {
    var limit = req.query.limit || 10;

    // get the max distance or set it to 8 kilometers
    var maxDistance = req.query.distance || 8;

    // we need to convert the distance to radians
    // the raduis of Earth is approximately 6371 kilometers
    maxDistance /= 6371;

    // get coordinates [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
    var coords = [];
    coords[0] = req.query.longitude || 0;
    coords[1] = req.query.latitude || 0;

    // find a location
    Location.find({
      loc: {
        $near: coords,
        $maxDistance: maxDistance
      }
    }).limit(limit).exec(function(err, locations) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json(500, err);
      }
      res.json(200, locations);
    });
  }
};
```

Esse é o `Json` que estou utilizando:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Igreja Matriz",
    "loc": [
      -49.974762,
      -23.160631

    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Prefeitura Jacarezinho",
    "loc": [
      -49.973597,
      -23.159745
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Lotérica",
    "loc": [
      -49.980461,
      -23.164231
    ]
  }
]
```

Eu passo os parâmetros por `QueryString` dessa forma: `http://localhost:3000/api/locations?longitude=-49.978440&latitude=-23.169557&distance=2`

Console e resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu consigo obter o resultado desejado?

Comment: Esse ` maxDistance /= 6371`  nao é um resquicio da formula Haversine? Pq no mongodb vc nao vai usar radianos

Comment: Você definiu as coordenadas como indexes da sua collection? Se sim, que tipo de index usou? Certifique-se disso usando no console do mongo o método getIndexes() na sua coleção de lugares

Comment: @LFZiron Não sei se é o index que to pensando, mas se for é 2d.

Comment: @user1576978 eu to dividindo por 111.12 agora, consegui mais precisão, porém tenho uma margem de erro de mais ou menos uns 100 metros

Comment: @Techies esse erro é aceitável em função da escala em que você está trabalhando e do sistema de coordenadas geográficas. Se você quiser uma precisão maior, deverá trabalhar com o sistema de projeção UTM. Dessa forma o raio informado será realmente em metros.

Comment: @MarcelloBenigno entendi, então essa margem de erro é normal do jeito que meu projeto está?

Comment: @Techies é sim!

Comment: @MarcelloBenigno se quiser elaborar uma pergunta pra explicar sobre eu irei marca-la como correta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O erro em questão é aceitável, tendo em vista a escala de trabalho e o sistema de referência utilizado. Uma alternativa para aumentar a precisão do raio, caso a sua área de estudo caiba em um fuso, seria utilizar o sistema de projeção UTM. Dessa forma o raio informado será realmente em metros.

Você pode também utilizar um banco de dados geográficos, como o PostgreSQL/PostGIS, que resolve esse tipo de situação facilmente. Sua consulta funcionaria da seguinte forma:

```
-- para um raio de 50 km = 50.000 m:
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom::geography,50000) AS geom
FROM nome_tabela
WHERE condicao;
```

Vou te passar alguns links sobre o assunto:

[PostGIS - Geometry or Geography find points within distance in meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65452/postgis-geometry-or-geography-find-points-within-distance-in-meters)

[PostGIS: extração de medidas em tabelas com coordenadas geográficas](http://profmarcello.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/postgis-extracao-de-medidas-em-tabelas.html)

[PostGIS - When to use Geography Data type over Geometry data type](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch04.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry)

Espero ter colaborado :)

Comment: Funciona só para PostgreSQL. Sabe alguma coisa em PHP, com MySQL?