# Localização usando NodeJS

Tags: node.js, geolocalização

Estou começando com o Node e estou criando uma aplicação onde eu queria pegar a localização atual do usuário e com essa localização eu possa fazer comparações e se possível até salvar no Banco.

#### Penso que irá funcionar desse jeito:

1. O usuário vai criar um grupo
2. Quando grupo for criado adicionar no banco junto com os detalhes do grupo, como nome, imagem, etc o local onde esse grupo foi criado.

Estou querendo salvar no banco a localização onde o grupo foi criado porque pretendo usar ela como comparação se o usuário for procurar novos grupos para ele fazer parte, mostrar os grupos que foram criados próximo a ele.

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer isso e se sim, como eu poderia fazer uma comparação para listar os grupos que estão em um raio de "x"KM

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124629/filtrar-locais-em-uma-area-de-x-km